# Building huge Single Page Application, framework choice etc

Tags: javascript, silverlight, porting

We currently have a large silverlight application (around 110 xaml views and over 40 custom controls).

We are looking at porting this to MVC (.net) and possibly use the SPA (single page application) pattern.

I can't really put all 110 views into a single html file. What I would like is some way to serve up a small start/loginpage and continually stream the other views asynchronously in the background and then store them in Web Storage for future use.

Is there any framework or some advice to accomplish this, or is there another way entirely that I'm missing?

Comment: I think I may have been somewhat unclear, the idea is to build it using HTML5 (web storage, maybe upshot.js, jquery etc). The most important bit: is there any pattern or framework that solves loading stuff in the background asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Managed Extensibility Framework by Microsoft.

http://mef.codeplex.com/

This may allow you to reduce the size of the XAP file so that the user doesn't have to download all 110 views when they're only interested in seeing a few.